# Dynamic value in <img>'s src attribute in dompdf

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dompdf

I am making a pdf of invoices for multiple companies. Every company has their own logo which they want to be going on the pdf. I am using dompdf for the sake of pdf generation. Now when hard code the value of src attribute with the relative path of the image it is rendered perfectly fine on the pdf. Eg in codeigniter:

```
$this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
$html = '<img style = "height: 140px; width: 180px;" src = "images/logo.png" />';
pdf_create($html, 'filename');
$data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
```

Now, as the image's relative path is going to change everytime depending on the client logged in I am trying to give src attribute a dynamic value like such:

```
$this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
$html = '<img style = "height: 140px; width: 180px;" src = '; $row->img; $html.=' />';
pdf_create($html, 'filename');
$data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
```

Where $row->img has the value = images/logo.png for a certain case.(the value is going to change depending on who is logged in).

Using the above code just gives me a blank space on the pdf, not even a broken image neither any error message. Please help me as its already taken one good day of mine.

Comments, suggestions, answers are highly appreciated Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$html = '<img style = "height: 140px; width: 180px;" src ="'.$row->img.'"/>';
```